# Fetching Docker container from AWS ECR, within a script, as a non-root user

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, root, amazon-ecr

I need to fetch a Docker image from AWS Elastic Container Registry and I need to do as a non-root user, apparently. I have a basic `install.sh` script that sets up my AWS EC2 instance, so every time I launch a new instance I can just theoretically run this script and it will install programs, fetch the container, and set up my system how I want it to be.

However, the workaround that Docker provides for managing Docker as a non-root user (see below) does not work when executed from within a script. The reason, as I understand, is that the last line executes a subshell, and I can't do that from within the script.

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}
newgrp docker  # cannot be executed from within a script
```

Is there any way around this?  Or do I just have to execute all three lines AND pull the container manually everytime?

Comment: If you're able to use `sudo` (as you are, demonstrably), why not just run `sudo docker` whenever you need to run `docker`?

Comment: `bash -l -c 'somecommand'` - the command here executes in a new login shell that will have the new group.

Comment: @larsks because I read that is insecure (someone could hack into the container via the applications inside it).

Comment: @jordanm thanks, but sorry, can you explain how I can use this?  I should run this bash line inside my existing bash script??  The first half of my script installs some tools, and the second half of this script does the docker stuff.  Once out of the script, I still need to run docker interactively as the non-root user.

Comment: Adding users to the `docker` group is pretty insecure: anyone who can `docker run` anything can pretty trivially root the host.  Since containers actually get launched by the Docker daemon, and the daemon is privileged, there's no security improvement from connecting to it from a non-root user.  I agree with @larsks: `sudo docker`, or run this setup script as root.

Comment: The reason the group is insecure is you root the host system by simply mounting / as a volume inside of a container.

Comment: "because I read that is insecure" You already have `sudo` access. You're not going to change the security of the system by using it. Whether you run `docker` using `sudo` or add yourself to the `docker` group, you still have the same access to `docker`, which ultimately is equivalent to having `root` access on  the host. You are needlessly complicating your life with the script you're trying to write.